# Kivy- different attributes for for loop generated buttons

Tags: python, button, kivy, kivy-language

I have been trying to make multiple buttons according to the number of files in a directory. And when each button pressed it should start to launch a different video file. I have for samples so far i can create 4 buttons but when i pressed it always triggers the last buttons on_release function. I have tried the make an array of buttons and they would have different instances but didn't succeed. Tried to get the id of the buttons but when i tried returning widget.id in a different function it returned the all the 4 buttons id's.

Is there any clear way to handle this kind of stuff. I would prefer to work with kivy file but i couldn't figure it out how to create buttons in a for loop. I can share the full code and kivy files also but it would be so messy. Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks in advance.

```
def createMultipleButton(self, dt):    
    root = Widget()
    size_y=150;
    size_x=150;

    for i in range(1):
    folderList = os.listdir(picture_path)
    if len(folderList)==0:
        time.sleep(1)
        break
    fileList = os.listdir(picture_path)
    print fileList

    for file in fileList:

            x = (picture_path+"/"+file)

            button = Button(id=str(file),text="" + str(file),size_hint=(None, None),height=size_y,width=size_x, pos_hint={'x': 0, 'y': 1},background_normal=x)
            button.bind(on_release=lambda btn:self.VideoContainer(str(file))        


            print file
            self.scrollview.content_layout.add_widget(button)


def VideoContainer(self,name):

    mylist=name.split('.')
    video = VideoPlayer(source="/home/linux/kivyFiles/kivyLogin/videoAssets/"+mylist[0]+".mp4", play=True)
    video.allow_stretch=True
    video.size=(500,500)
    video.pos=(400,400)
    self.add_widget(video)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Names in function bodies are evaluated when the function is executed, not when they are declared. `file` value is the last element of `fileList` when the lambda fuction is executed (button is pressed).

Your lambda fuction should be:

```
button.bind(on_release=lambda btn, f=file: self.VideoContainer(f))
```

But I recommend using `functools.partial` instead of lambda functions to pass callbacks arguments:

```
from functools import partial

button.bind(on_release=partial(self.VideoContainer, file))

def VideoContainer(self, name, btn):
    #....
```

Comment: It works like a charm. I have been trying to solve that issue over 8 hours. Thank you.